# Heroku, schedule new Dyno sleeptime

Tags: heroku, server, dyno

With the announcement of the new Dyno pricing on Heroku I had some questions about the mechanics of the new free Dyno.

I was wondering if it was possible to schedule sleep time for a Dyno. This way I could make sure that my application is down while most of my users are sleeping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Your app will automatically sleep when it doesn't get any requests for 30 minutes, and will be awaken if a request comes in.
If you have exceeded your daily quota, the app will just not be awaken.